# How to prevent warp-cli from overwriting /etc/resolv.conf file

Tags: wireless, network-manager, dns, resolv.conf

Whenever I connect with [warp-cli](https://developers.cloudflare.com/warp-client/get-started/linux/), it always generates a new `resolv.conf` file, as a result, if I ever disconnect from `warp-cli` I lose my internet connection, even though `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping localhost` both send and receive without any packet loss.

I need my `resolv.conf` file to be as follows in order to be online:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.1.9
```

How can I prevent `warp-cli` from generating a new `resolv.conf` file that overwrites the default working one? Thank you!

Comment: There is a warning inside the file: "# Do not edit." with an explanation why not to do this. If that is how warp-cli work ditch it and find a version compatible with current resolve.conf: warp-cli needs to APPEND to the file as all the other procedures (like NM, dhclient etc) do. And do tell them on their github page about this just in case it is possible to do have it append. I could not find it ;-)

Comment: Need more info.  What OS?  /etc/resolve.conf is a systemd managed file after Bionic.

Comment: @Frobozz my OS is ```Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS```, ```5.15.0-67-generic``` linux core, would that be of any help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not all that familiar with warp-cli but I would not imagine it would be altering **/etc/resolve.conf**

In later versions of Ubuntu (possibly since 18.04), **/etc/resolve.conf** is automatically generated by **systemd** (more accurately, replace by a symbolic link to a systemd generated file).  Any changes made will simply be overwritten.  However, you can define *how* it gets generated and behaves by editing one of the **resolved.conf** files under /etc/systemd.

Example: define the DNS servers and search domains by editing **/etc/systemd/resolved.conf** adding the following:

```
DNS=x.x.x.x y.y.y.y
FallbackDNS=z.z.z.z
Domains=mydomain.org corp.mydomain.org
```

(Note that nameserver will always be 127.0.0.53 in /etc/resolv.conf but lookups use those you defined)

Restart the service with `systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`

Watch what **resolved** is up to with `journalctl -u systemd-resolved -f`

You may find the **resolvectl** tool worth checking out as well.

See `man 5 resolved.conf` and `man resolvectl` for all the details.